# PHP apc caching variables and periodically update database

Tags: php, database, variables, caching, apc

Ok I've seen many questions but none actually solve my 'problem'.

To put it simple. I have some sort of object that can be 'liked' so to speak. If someone likes it,  the script is run ( through AJAX) that updates field in db with likes=likes+1.
But if many people are online and liking it means for each like i get 1 query and it puts much weight on my db connections. 
I therefore got APC. But i want it to store those likes in cache, and with each'like' it actually increments some variable  by 1,but before the variable is deleted from cache i want it to be inserted in database.
What is the best practice for this process?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Ok, sry for lack of info.
Well actually I have dedi server, and I have some twitter-like site. What happens is that number of visitors is increasing each day, and I start getting error logs that my sql connection limit is exceeded. Before that with shared hosting i had problem with heavy php scripts (especially selects) and i had almost no caching. So I want to try APC to minimize number of mysqli connections, and one of the most usual sql tasks is like/dislike. and it only increments a value.
I will also cache selects but i dont care if their time expire, since no info is lost...

I dont have any triggers, but I feel that it can be done much simpler with some kind of caching - incrementing the 'likes' and on every 50 likes, make 1 sql update. Sometimes there is more than 500people online and everybody is likeing some comments/posts so thats why I guess it generate a lot of queries.

If you guys think that update is not that heavy I won't bother too much with this, and will only cover heavy selects.

I have a simple structure:

Table1- Posts: columns:1.ID 2.text 3.likes 4.dislikes...
Table2 - comments:  columns: 1.ID 2.text 3.Posts_ID , 4.likes...

about the code it is as simple as it can be:

```
if( Mr.smith already liked){
    do nothing with database
}
else {
    mysqli->query("Update Posts set likes = likes+1");
}
```

Any hint is highly appreciated.

Comment: What have you already done ? No source code ?

Comment: How many writes per second are you actually getting, and what else is going on (triggers, etc) which could be translating into such a devastatingly heavy load?

Comment: Unless your database server is seriously underpowered / already at its performance limit, it's unlikely that a simple query like this would cause such a load. Sharing the exact table definition & code for the mysql update could help us to see if there's anything out of order in the update.

Comment: Ok I've edited question in order to provide you with more info.
Also, Ive noticed that APC doesnt always return true eventhough it should. Ive learned somewhere that it is due to FastCGI. Can someone tell me a bit more about it and should i turn off mmap support?